# Undeclared identifier when promoting control

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to understand how to promote a custom widget in the Qt Designer.

I created a widget and promoted it as:

[image]

But when I try to compile, I'm getting an `undeclared identifier` error on this line:

```cpp
widget = new CustomTitleBar(centralWidget);
```

Source files:

`app.h`

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include "ui_app.h"

class app : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    app(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~app();

private:
    Ui::appClass ui;
};



class CustomTitleBar : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomTitleBar(QWidget* parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
       setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    }

    QPoint mpos;

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            QPoint diff = event->pos() - mpos;
            QPoint newpos = this->pos() + diff;
            this->parentWidget()->move(newpos);
        }
    }
};
```

`ui_app.h`

```cpp
#ifndef UI_APP_H
#define UI_APP_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include "app.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_appClass
{
public:
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    CustomTitleBar *widget;
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QToolBar *mainToolBar;
    QStatusBar *statusBar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *appClass)
    {
        if (appClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            appClass->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("appClass"));
        appClass->resize(600, 400);
        centralWidget = new QWidget(appClass);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralWidget"));
        widget = new CustomTitleBar(centralWidget);
        widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("widget"));
        widget->setGeometry(QRect(320, 20, 161, 281));
        appClass->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(appClass);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 600, 22));
        appClass->setMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(appClass);
        mainToolBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("mainToolBar"));
        appClass->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
        statusBar = new QStatusBar(appClass);
        statusBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusBar"));
        appClass->setStatusBar(statusBar);

        retranslateUi(appClass);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(appClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *appClass)
    {
        appClass->setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication::translate("appClass", "app", nullptr));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class appClass: public Ui_appClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_APP_H
```

Comment: You have two header files including each other. This cannot work. Why do you need `#include "ui_app.h"` in `app.h`? Try removing that line.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. these includes were added automatic by Qt itself. If i  remove `ui_app.h` from `app.h` i get a lot of errors: https://i.imgur.com/nQZuHYx.png

Comment: Please don't post images of errors.

Comment: You of course need all the include directives in app.h that it is currently missing. What is QMainWindow, where is it defined? What is QWidget? Etc etc. This will still not work bit it will get you a direction of how to rework your code.